# Keep getting attribute error when trying to use I/O

Tags: python, io

So basically I am trying to develop some sort of basic understanding of I/O, I wrote this program and I'm trying to fix any bugs,

On line 11

```
fh.open('updated' + filename, 'w')
```

I keep getting an

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'open'
```

whats wrong and how do i fix it? Also if there are any additional errors(not syntax) that you see, let me know!

```
filename = 'sample.txt'
fh = open(filename, 'r')
lines = fh.readlines()
x = 0
for i in lines:
  if i == '\n':
    lines[x] = lines[x]*2
  else:
    lines[x] = ''
fh.close()
fh.open('updated' + filename, 'w')
for line in lines:
  fh.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open) is a built-in function. Do

```
fh = open('updated' + filename, 'w')
```

Even better:

```
with open('updated' + filename, 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(line)
```

Hint: Use four spaces for each level of indention.

Answer (score 0):

Try another `fh = open(...)`.

`open()` is a builtin function, not a file object attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is okay.But following are my comments
1] If you want to read one file and write that file in another file.You will miss first line in your case.As well as you need to close your file is which you are updating.
2] Use try .. except blocks in your code